# Populating Tables from Database in Angular. Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

Although i have seen similar questions, none have solved my problem. any sort of help would be appreciated. I am trying to populate my table with information from my db. i can log the information but when i try to iterate i get this error.

Admin.HTML

```
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getData()">Customer Data</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
      <table class="col table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col-2">Name</th>
            <th scope="">Phone Number</th>
            <th scope="col-2">Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            <th scope="row">{{ customer.name }}</th>
            <td>{{ customer.number }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.email }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

admin.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { CustomerData } from '../customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  customers = [];

  constructor(private customerData: CustomerData) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getData() {
    this.customerData.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (customers: any[]) => this.customers = customers,
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class CustomerData {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    getData() {
        return this.http.get('link yo database')
        .pipe(map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                return data.result || data || [];
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` in your service and show output. Also you should use the new `HttpClient` if using angular 4+

Comment: It seems `data.result` contains one more property which has all your data. could you please share `data.result`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data you get from your DB is not an Array(). That will not be iterable by *ngFor. The response seems to be an object or something else.

I created a small Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ap58xs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustomer.service.ts

It may help.

Comment: It is not an array. i suspect it is formgroup as it was a formgroup i converted to JSON format to populate the DB. Your solution is interesting but it would involve me using a different approach totally. Could you please advice me on how to convert a formGroup(which is not iterable) into an array.

Comment: You may find some answers here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray. Also a nice read about ReactiveForms: https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a